# std::stoi integer limit

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm confused about the limit on integer strings passed into `std::stoi`. An integer is 32-bits am I not mistaken? In a signed 32-bit integer can range from −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. I've input "300000000" (three hundred million) into it and got an out of range exception thrown. It seems like its enforcing a 16-bit limit. `std::stol` seems to work on the other hand. I've been trying to find some documentation that states the limits of these functions but I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: Using which C library and what copmpiler, for what hardware (processor)?

Comment: you may use unsigned int

Comment: Works for me. Show us your code and tell us about your architecture/compiler.

Comment: Yes, works fine here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4jvUZA$3

Comment: An `int` is at least 16 bit. That much the C standard guarantees you. If you need more, you either use `long`, or rely on the extended guarantee provided by your C implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the functions that impose limits, but the integral types themselves; the functions throw an exception if the input is too large to fit. To see what the maximum and minimum values are for any integral type, use `std::numeric_limits<the_type>::max()` and `std::numeric_limits<the_type>::min()`.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I'm mysteriously not having the issue anymore. I must've done something wrong. Someone proposed that C++11 be removed as a tag from my post. Isn't this a C++11 feature?